# Have famous rabbis ever converted to Islam?

Tags: religion, islam, jews

By "famous [rabbi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi)" I mean someone who was actually known in at least one community as an authority on [Jewish law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halakha), not just one who successfully completed rabbinical training.

Comment: O.K., it is not claimed that Columbus was a Muslim, but there is a [widespread claim in Muslim circles](http://muslimwiki.com/mw/index.php/Christopher_Columbus) that he relied on an Arab book and Muslim navigators to discover the Americas, for which there is [no evidence really](http://old.nationalreview.com/comment/spencer200409150556.asp). It is also a widespread claim that Muslim ships discovered the Americas centuries before Columbus, also without evidence.

Comment: I suggest you qualify a bit what you mean by conversion: If someone acts publicly as a Muslim but in private remains an observant Jew (not so difficult to do) is that called conversion? Does coerced conversion count?

Comment: Suggest that you remove the word famous and rephrase the question. "Who is the most authoritative Rabbi to convert to Islam?" "Famous" is distracting the discussion from what seems to be your core question.

Comment: @Coelacanth - I was under impression that conversion to Islam has some well defined rules and formal process?

Comment: @DVK - I really don't know. But I'm not sure that's relevant if you're just "going through the motions" because you're forced, but don't mean it.

Comment: Question is "who is a rabbi" not "what does documentary interpretation reveal regarding the past."  Wrong board: wrong humanity for this board.

Answer (score 14):

**Yes**

Following are some examples of leading Rabbis who converted to Islam:

- [Abdullah Bin Salam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdullah,_son_of_Salam#Early_years): He is the first Jewish Rabbi to convert to Islam. Before conversion he was called as Husayn bun Salam. The conversion happened at the time of Muhammad himself.
  Following narrative about his conversion is reported in the  collection of authentic [historical traditions](http://sunnah.com/urn/31100) of Islam:

> Prophet Muhammad asks the Jewish community:
>
> “What is the status of Al-Husayn ibn Salam among you?”
>
> “He is our sayyid (leader) and the son of our sayyid.  He is our rabbi
> and our alim (scholar), the son of our rabbi and alim.”
>
> “If you come to know that he has accepted Islam, would you accept
> Islam also?” asked the Prophet.
>
> “God forbid! He would not accept Islam.  May God protect him from
> accepting Islam,” they said, horrified.
>
> At this point I came out in full view of them and announced: “O
> assembly of Jews! Be conscious of God and accept what Muhammad has
> brought.  By God, you certainly know that he is the Messenger of God
> and you can find prophecies about him and mention of his name and
> characteristics in your Torah.  I for my part declare that he is the
> Messenger of God.  I have faith in him and believe that he is true.  I
> know him.”

- [Sabatai Zevi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatai_Zevi) : Was a very famous Rabbi of his time , to the extent many of the Jews started believing him as the Messiah and he claimed it too. Some people claim that he was coerced , this might be true but later in life he truly accepted Islam and also bought 300 Jewish families to Islam:

> Sarah and approximately 300 families among Sabbatai's followers also
> converted to Islam. These new Muslims thereafter were known as dönmeh
> (converts).[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatai_Zevi) The sultan's officials ordered Sabbatai to take an
> additional wife to demonstrate his conversion. Some days after his
> conversion he wrote to Smyrna: "God has made me an Ishmaelite; He
> commanded, and it was done. The ninth day of my
> regeneration."

- [Maimonides - (RAMBAM)](http://chabadsociologist.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/the-rambam-may-have-been-forced-to-convert-to-islam-historian-j-kraemer/) : Many historical sources seem to support the idea that RAMBAM may have been coerced into converting to Islam, although this is highly debatable:

[Some references:](http://www.hashlamah.org/co-worship.html)

> A Muslim historian, Ibn al-Qifti (1172-1248) reports nothing less than
> that the Rambam himself, on numerous occasions, voluntarily went to
> mosques to pray 1, under no compulsion and seeing no contradiction
> with his Judaism. Ibn al-Qifti notes that this was towards the end of
> Maimonides’ life and was not an event of his youth, under fear of the
> Al-Mohades who had invaded Al-Andalus in his youth.1
>
> Kenneth Seeskin
> writes, in The Cambridge Companion to Maimonides, “although Ibn
> al-Qifti’s book has come down to us in a later recension, and contains
> some errors, we have no reason to doubt the information on
> Maimonides.”2
>
> 1 Tarikh al-Hukama, p. 318, trans. Kraemer in Fine, 2001. 424.
>
> 2 Kenneth Seeskin, The Cambridge Companion to Maimonides, (Cambridge
> University Press: 2005)

Moreover many of the famous works of Maimonides are derivatives of the Islamic literature by Muslim scholars. [The Rabbis of the time of Maimonides condemned  RamBam for bringing Islamic scholarship into Judaism](http://failedmessiah.typepad.com/failed_messiahcom/2009/01/maimonides-the.html). Later down the line his grandson Obadyah (1228-1265) accepted and followed the mystical notions of the Muslim Sufis and wrote the classical treatise on Islamic sufism interlaced with Jewish thoughts titled as [The Treatise of the Pool: Al-Mawala Al Hawdiyya](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0900860871).

A [UNESCO historical document](http://unesdoc.unesco.org/images/0007/000704/070484eo.pdf) states the following on Pg 14:

> Some biographers maintain that Maimonides may even have been converted
> to Islam.

Also, in the French version of a [December 2010 report of UNESCO](http://www.unesco.org/new/fileadmin/MULTIMEDIA/HQ/SC/pdf/sc_usr05_arab_fr.pdf) we find the following report:

> Une fois Tolède reprise aux Maures par les croisés en 1085, les
> savants européens y affluèrent afin de traduire les anciens textes
> classiques du grec (que l’Europe avait oubliés) vers l’arabe et
> l’hébreu, puis le latin, rendant ce la première partie du Moyen Âge
> européen (1100-1543), les noms de quelques savants européens
> apparaissaient dans la littérature scientifique à côté d’un grand
> nombre de savants musulmans, parmi lesquels Ibn Rushd (Averroès),
> Moussa ibn Maïmoun (Maïmonide), Tousi et Ibn Nafis.
>
> After the recovery of Toledo from the Moors by the Crusaders in 1085,
> European scholars flocked there to translate the ancient classical
> texts from the Greek (which Europe had forgotten) to Arabic and Hebrew
> and Latin, making it the first part of the European Middle Ages
> (1100-1543), the names of some European scholars appeared in
> scientific literature next to a large number of **Muslim scholars**,
> including Ibn Rushd (Averroes), **Maimouna Ibn Moussa (Maimonides)**,
> Tousi and Ibn Nafis.

Having said that, although RAMBAM may have at some point feigned conversion because of social and political pressure, it does not appear that was truly a believer in Islam. See [Historian reviews evidence of Rambam’s forced conversion](https://iamaqwerty.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/historian-reviews-evidence-of-rambams-forced-conversion/)

Another point of view regarding Rambam can be that he practiced both Judaism and Islam simultaneously, In Jewish Encyclopedia , we find the fact that , belief in Muhammad pbuh is not equatable to Idolatry and hence wont demand sacrifice of life as is the case of the law for Idolatry, thus making Islam simply as a sect within Judaism:

> Rabbi M. Friedländer in ("Guide of the Perplexed," i., xvii., xxxiii.,
> et seq.), in which Islam is declared to be **simply a belief in
> Mohammed**, and that Islam is not idolatry, to avoid which only the Law
> demands the sacrifice of life.

[Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4634-conversion-to-islam)

Hence it is halachically possible for a Jew to become a Muslim , [A Jew wont loose his Jewishness](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/can-a-jew-lose-their-jewish-status) by accepting Islam. Rambam realized this very well as quoted above in his most popular work. hence it is fair seeming that he purposely did not show any resistance to Dawah on him and accepted Islam. His acceptance of Islam may not be genuine but he was a very ambitious and rational intellectual whose conversion was a pragmatic decision which would help him gain acceptance and position of influence from the Sultans of the time as reported by  Al-Baghdadi in Seeskin:

> he was of superior merit, but love of authority and serving powerful
> people prevailed over him
>
> was too much concerned with worldly successand frequenting the great
> as their physician

[Reports from Kenneth Seeskin, The Cambridge Companion to Maimonides, (Cambridge University Press: 2005)](http://www.google.co.il/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Vhu33_bMRmYC&oi=fnd&pg=PA10&dq=maimonides%20islam%20conversion&ots=amNeIYnuta&sig=VK4RXIkjwphm28byTLap-YXb9Ks&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Regarding conversion:

> Kraemer also found sources that indicate that while in Fustat (old
> Cairo), the Rambam was confronted by a man named Abu ‘l-’Arab ibn
> Mu’isha, a jurist from Andalusia, who recognized that the leader of
> the Jewish community in Egypt was no longer practicing Islam (a crime
> punishable by death under Islamic law). The Rambam managed to escape
> persecution although the historical records give conflicting reports
> as to how that happened.

- [Moisha Krivitsky, Ex-Rabbi, Dagestan](http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/591/): He is reported to be the Rabbi of Makhachkala synagogue in Dagestan
- [Abu Nasr Samuel ibn Judah ibn Abbas (Samuel of Morocco)](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4634-conversion-to-islam): He was the rabbi of the Moroccon city of Fez and  author of the "IfḦam al-Yahud"(Confutation of the Jews) a polemical treatise written addressed to the Jews after conversion to Islam. [The Jewish encyclopedia summarizes his work](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/174-abbas-samuel-abu-nasr-ibn):

> In this work (Ifham Yahud) he points out that from time to time the
> abrogation of the Law is necessary and that, in fact, it has often
> occurred in Judaism. He tries to prove the prophetic character of
> Jesus and of Mohammed; claiming that the first of these is referred to
> in Gen. xlix. 10, and the latter in Gen. xvii. 2 ( has numerically the
> same value as  Mohammed). He affirms that the Jews of his time possess
> the Torah of Ezra and not that of Moses, and that too many laws have
> been added by the sages of the Mishnah and the Gemara.

Samuel makes the curious statement in ("Monatsschrift," xlii. 260) :

> that most of the Karaites had gone over to Islam, because their system
> is free from all the absurdities of the Rabbinites, and their theology
> not so different from that of the Mohammedans.

- [Yosef Cohen](http://revert2islamtoday.blogspot.in/2013/06/former-jewish-rabbi-and-his-family.html) A former rabbi belonging to the Satmar Hasidic community in Brooklyn.

Comment: Several comments were marked as obsolete. Given that this answer is completely unlike its original form, I didn't really have the patience to wade through all 26 to figure out which were still relevant, so I've purged them all. Everyone gets a do-over.

Comment: Ok, do-over: I really appreciate that you've modified the answer to include the feigned conversion angle. I'd be happy to reverse the downvote if you could also remove the part (From "Another point of view" to "frequenting the great as their physician") because it's pure conjecture, not really supported by the sources.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I have substantiated it with the sources which are linked e.g the latter is a direct quote from seeskin

Comment: Okay, but this is not Seeskin's comment - he credits it to Al-Baghdadi, who was according to Seeskin, "hypercritical of his contemporaries". So it'd be better to make sure the quotes are properly attributed.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I edited it

Comment: Thanks, that's better, but frankly I still think it's not quite right, that bit about his being ambitious - it comes across as if he might have converted for worldly gain, while we do know that he was forced to convert and relapsed (if converted at all); so it's a false accusation, isn't it?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I just posted the various reports , the real truth we cant know but that does not mean that we dont report it. The allegation of "forced" conversion comes from Jewish sources and western sources. It is reported that Some Muslim sources record him as a Muslim scholar too. Moreover regarding simultaneous practice than Ibn Qiftis quote is enough for that

Comment: Okay, agree to differ, then.

Comment: specifically I am referring to :" under no compulsion and seeing no contradiction with his Judaism. Ibn al-Qifti notes that this was towards the end of Maimonides’ life and was not an event of his youth, under fear of the Al-Mohades who had invaded Al-Andalus in his youth"

Comment: Can you give me a precise pointer for the "no compulsion quote"? Seeskin tells alQifti's story very differently from you - he makes clear it was a feigned conversion.

Comment: -1 : This answer has become a mish-mosh of inconsistencies, irrelevancies, and bad sources, with a seeming agenda to prove that RAMBAM converted to Islam, although there is **no credible evidence** whatsoever cited for this.  (And what RAMBAM's grandson did or did not do has **no bearing whatsoever** on the question.) This answer needs a complete makeover.

Comment: @Coelacanth you yourself had agreed to the answer in the deleted comments and had given an upvote, Your last edit was very aggressive. I clearly gave the evidences to clarify that there are indeed reports which suggests that he converted. Moreover you removed two entries like samuel of morrocco.

Comment: @Ali - this could be a very good answer. But you seem to insist or bringing in material which is irrelevant and sometimes highly questionable. Four paragraphs can cover the whole thing sufficiently and accurately.

Comment: @Coelacanth Well I have clearly cited a UNESCO document which reports that "Some biographers maintain that Maimonides may even have been converted to Islam.
" I have been unbiased and reported all the possiblities like he may have been coerced, practiced both etc

Comment: @Ali - the comments have all been made. It's your answer...

Comment: This answer seems quite desperate. Claiming that Joseph Cohen is an example. For those that don't know.. Joseph Cohen or Joseph Kaplan, was never a rabbi, he was a Jew that was secular, became religious (black hat), then became muslim spoke of how he'd love his sons to be martyrs killing jews, and was investigated by the FBI after a bomb threat against a Jewish organization. He is a fundamentalist muslim now(has been since around 2000), but was never a rabbi. And the question asked for notable rabbis.

Comment: Maimonides(who you call a Muslim) in his Laws of concerning the coming of messiah, referred to Mohammed as a mad man.. and was very critical of muslims in his letter to yemen, and a letter published in english by andrew bostom. And in one letter he said it's OK to teach torah to christians but not to muslims because they do not accept the text and would pervert what they are taught. And if I recall  he had great praise for a convert to judaism from islam, for that man making that transition against the man's own  family, but for the sake of truth.

Comment: Your first example is "sourced" in Islamic tradition, which doesn't mean anything without support.  Having a story saying "one of them converted to us" doesn't mean anything without independent verification.  Your second example isn't sourced at all (w.r.t. it being sincere).  Your claims about the Rambam have been covered by other comments already.

Answer (score 3):

The 17th century Sephardic cult leader and kabbalist [Sabbatai Zevi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatai_Zevi) might be considered an example, though his conversion was coerced.

He claimed to be the Jewish Messiah and was invited by his Ottoman captors to choose between putting this to a probably fatal test, or converting to Islam.

Comment: -1 - Sabbatai Zevi was in no way, shape or form a "famous rabbi". He was trained as a rabbi, but he was famous for being a claimed messiah, NOT for his rabbinical knowledge.

Comment: @DVK it is common in Judasim that a rabbi reaches such heights in popularity that would cause him to think that he is the messiah e.g : Lubervitche Rabbi of Chabad and many others , proclaiming messiahhood is the culmination of popularity of a Rabbi

Comment: @Ali - leaving aside the accuracy of your example, Zevi was the opposote - he was NOT popular as a famous Rabbi. He was popular as wannabe Messiah (and NOT a noted Rabbinical scholar/sage).

Comment: @DVK - agreed - -1 - bad answer.

Comment: @Ali - **VERY WRONG**. The question asks specifically for someone noted as "an authority on Jewish law." SZ was never such a person. He was never an esteemed Rabbi, was banished and 'excommunicated' by mainstream rabbis and his followers consisted primarily of ignorants and malcontents whom he managed to persuade to his opinions, often through means that were less than honorable....

Comment: Sorry, -1. What @DVK said.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: Whatever you wish - you asked for a famous rabbi. You may have fallen into DVK and Coelacanth's "[no true Scotsman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)" trap. In fact his claims to authority not restricted to a small group, but instead divided Jewish communities with most synagogues praying for him, and were for example endorsed by the Chief Rabbi of Amsterdam.

Comment: @Henry - there's a difference between being famous and famous for X. Paris Hilton is famous. And she's a movie actress. But she's NOT in any way, shape or form famous **as a movie actress**. Zevi had followers NOT because he was a big-time famous rabbi, but simply because he claimed to be a Messiah. Had he not made that claim, he'd have been a little-known rabbi from somewhere, known to his congregarion and may be some neighbours. Can you produce a single notable work of Rabbinical/Talmudic scholarship that he produced separately from his Messianic claims?

Comment: @DVK Actually, I don't think he even had a congregation before he claimed he was Messiah.

Comment: @Henry - He was **famous** as a **cult leader**.

Comment: @Coelacanth - Indeed, and for his followers he removed some of the pre-Messianic rituals such as fasting on the Tenth of Tevet, so they accepted him as able to give legal rulings.

Comment: @Henry - "so they accepted him as able to give legal rulings". No different than every cult leader. That doesn't make him a rabbi.

Answer (score 2):

No. If conversion is contemplated, apostacy has occurred. The person is no longer a Rabbi though he may have previously been awarded that title.

A Rabbi is one who has received semikah, ordination, to teach and judge in a stipulated manner. He is entitled to certain special forms of compensation and a higher degree of protection and respect so long as he discharges Rabbinical functions. However, except under extreme and sudden duress or as a result of insanity, it can't be the case that a Rabbi remained a Rabbi at a time when he converted to another Religion. So, technically, an apostate converts, a Rabbi doesn't- save due to sudden insanity or extreme torture or the threat of death.

On the other hand, it is certainly true that there have been periods when it was not clear whether apostacy had actually occurred. Perhaps Islam was complementary to Judaism? That doubt has been resolved. On the other hand, suppose your Rabbi is doing Yoga or Tai Chi. Does that represent a dangerous embrace of an alien, perhaps idolatrous, religion (avodah zarah)? In the case of Yoga, this matter has been resolved in Israel such that some aspects of it are kosher while others are not. This is a matter which required detailed inquiry and examination. Similarly, if a person who has the title of Rabbi and whose religious judgments have been followed, suddenly converts to Islam, there would have to be a proper examination to see whether or not he was truly discharging Rabbinical functions in the stipulated manner at the time when he began contemplating conversion. It is likely that he did something which caused him to become an apostate before the moment of conversion. If such is not the case, then the question arises- 'should Jews follow the example of this Rabbi? Should they too convert?' Clearly, accepting that a convert is a Rabbi at the time of conversion means accepting that the Holy Covenant is mutable. This must be rejected or else schisms will flourish and the Religion will decline.

On the other hand, it is certainly true that there are numerous communities across the globe who claim to have Jewish heritage. Some mention a particular Rabbi as having founded their lineage. There are instances where the two Chief Rabbis of Israel have investigated such claims with a view to determine if such people qualify for Aliyah under the 'right to return'. It would be interesting to find out whether, in granting such rights, Israel has tacitly admitted that Rabbis could convert while remaining Rabbis.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which I do really appreciate. But this is not quite what I was looking for - I am not interested in explaining (away..?) such conversions in a theological or religious law framework. All I was asking about are the bare facts. For my purpose anybody who at time T was an acknowledged Rabbi and at time T+DT, DT>0 converted to Islam counts.

Comment: A Rabbi who converted would cease to be authoritative and thus would get expunged from the record. Thus, even if there was a contemporary account saying 'X was a great rabbi and he converted', it would be difficult to prove that he really was authoritative in his own time. On the other hand, it may be that an Israeli lawyer would have information re. a tacit admission of what you seek since some convert communities prided themselves on Rabbinical origin.